# Blender not recognizing GPU

Tags: rendering

I am using blender 2.66.1 and I have a gtx 580 installed. I am using Zorin OS 7, which is based on Ubuntu 13.04. I am in the blender preferences and for 'Compute Device' I only have the CPU. Whats wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. It seems the problem was not blender related. JUst run these lines of code and restart and update to the newest driver and you should be good.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install nvidia-current nvidia-settings
```